# Is the intersection of these given sequences the empty set?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Given $a_n = 0, b_n = \frac{1}{n} \forall n\geq1$

Does this imply the sequence of nested open intervals $((a_n, b_n))^{\infty}_{n = 1}$ has the condition satisfied that $\cap^{\infty}_{n=1} (a_n, b_n) = \emptyset$ ??

A user on a different thread claimed it did, my question is isn't the value $0$ part of the intersection? While $0$ is not explicitly in any sequence because the intervals are open, they go from (0,1), (0, 1/2), (0,1/3), ..... , (0, 1/99999999) and so forth, they each share that initial starting point. Hence their intersection cannot be $\emptyset$, can it?

Comment: The initial starting point $0$ is not a $member$ of $any$  
 $(a_n,b_n)$ so it certainly cannot be  a member  of all of them.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Assume some $x>0$ is in the intersection. Can you find a contradiction to this assumption? That is, can you find one of the intervals in the intersection not containing $x$?

Responding to your edit: 0 is not in any of the sets under consideration, so it cannot be in the intersection.

Comment: Uhh, suppose for example we chose $x \ge 1/3$, many intervals with n greater than 3 do not have this in their intersection. I do not get what you are trying to say though...

Comment: If you find one interval that does not contain x, then x is not in the intersection. Notice we chose x arbitrarily, so our argument proves that no x>0 is in the intersection. So the intersection is empty.

Comment: I see what you're trying to say lad, there will always be a smaller number not in the intersection. Thanks!